# If A is a component of B, then what is B in relation to A?

Tags: meaning, terminology

For example, we have the concepts of *mentor* and *mentee*, or *trainer* and *trainee*: If person A is a trainer of person B than person B is a trainee of person A. How can I apply a similar concept for **component** type of relations? If item A is component of item B than item B is *componentee?* of item A? Is there even a word to explain this kind of relation?

Comment: A set of components , a system ?

Comment: A Mentor is not "one who ments," but rather "someone who acts like the character in *The Odyssey* whose name was Mentor".  Mentor was a father figure to young Telemachus while Odysseus was at war.  Thus, "Mentee" is not a good choice for an example of the word relationship you are talking about.

Comment: @Jeff - Yet "mentee" is quite commonly used, as there is no better unambiguous term.

Comment: Depending on the items, you could use component - owner. For example, *that touchpad is a **component** of my laptop* -- *my laptop is the **owner** of that touchpad*

Comment: module, package, container

Comment: Words like _assembly_, _composite_, _container_ encompass the meaning that B is _made of components_, but I can't think of a single word that conveys both that _and_ that A is one of those components. You can create phrases to express this ("_B is an assembly including A_", "_B is a composite including A_"), but I'm not sure if that's really what you want (hence this being a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Searching Google Books for the phrase
 ["is comprised of many components"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22lunch%20date%20with%20friends%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=KeMQVZamEsOhgwSGyIFI#q=%22is%20comprised%20of%20many%20components%22&tbm=bks&start=50) shows "a system" as a quite frequent **antecedent** of it. "A unit" is another candidate.

Generally, this is a  ["**whole-to-part**"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22lunch%20date%20with%20friends%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=KeMQVZamEsOhgwSGyIFI#tbm=bks&q=%22whole%20to%20part%22) or a "**parent-to-component**" type of relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The term **[has-a relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)** comes to mind:

```
composition relationship where one object (often called the constituted object, or part/constituent/member object) "belongs to" (is part or member of) another object (called the composite type), and behaves according to the rules of ownership.
```

Answer (score 0):

The *-or* and *-ee* suffixes (e.g. lessor, lessee, grantor, grantee, donor, donee) express a giving/receiving relationship.  That relationship has nothing to do with the assembly/component relationship.  I know of no suffix that identifies the assembl*age* or a compon*ent* apart from the ones they already have.